# self.opt_op = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss) TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'

Tags: python, tensorflow

The code can execute in tensorflow v1,but when i execute the code in tensorflow v2,it report errors:
TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var_list'

```
def build(self):
    self._build()
    self.outputs = self.concat_vec
    self._loss()
    self._accuracy()
    self.opt_op = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
```

but i don't know what variable to add

Comment: well you can minimizing loss with respect to trainable variables. Therefore, you should add  something like `self.model.trainable_variables`.

Comment: the variables in code are define as:           with tf.variable_scope(self.name + '_vars'):
            for i in range(1):
                self.vars['weights_' + str(i)] = uniform([input_dim, output_dim],
                                                        name='weights_' + str(i))
            if self.bias:
                self.vars['bias'] = uniform([output_dim], name='bias')    So i should add weight and bias?

Comment: As the minimize() function accepts two arguments to compute, you may need to provide var_list along with the loss() which caused this error. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize) for your reference.